# R: Separating values that fall within a certain date range

Tags: r

I searched for quite a while and unfortunately couldn't find any previous posts that attempt to do what I need to do. I have a data table with 46 rows that is indexed by date (lets call this `Data1`. `Data1` covers sporadic values over three years' time (2001-2003). I also have a vector of dates 362 values long which covers the same date range (we'll call this `Data2`).

I need to assign values to the dates in `Data2` based on the values in `Data1`. More specifically, the dates in `Data2` that are a week before a given date in `Data1` should be set to the value for that date in `Data1`. Here's an example using the first value in `Data1` and dates in `Data2`:

Data1:

```
DATE         VALUE
2001-01-24     17
2001-02-17     21
2001-03-20     18
```

Data2:

```
DATE         VALUE
2001-01-20
2001-01-23
2001-02-11
2001-02-15
2001-03-18
```

After receiving your help I should be able to turn `Data2` into the following:

```
DATE         VALUE
2001-01-20     17
2001-01-23     17
2001-02-11     21
2001-02-15     21
2001-03-18     18
```

As the dates fell into the week before the date in `Data1`, and therefore have the same value as the first value in `Data1`.

Hopefully what I'm trying to do is clear here. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you provide more example data so its clearer how this would work?

Comment: I added more sample data. Hopefully it's more clear now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's helpful to use the `dput()` function to provide sample data when asking a question.  For example:

```
Data1 <- structure(list(DATE = structure(c(11346, 11370, 11401), class = "Date"), 
    VALUE = c(17L, 21L, 18L)), .Names = c("DATE", "VALUE"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
Data2 <- structure(list(DATE = structure(c(11342, 11345, 11364, 11368, 11399), 
    class = "Date")), .Names = "DATE", 
    row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

You could use the `wday()` function in the `lubridate` package to help you define your "week" and then merge the two data sets based on this definition of week.  For example:

```
library(lubridate)

Data1$week <- as.numeric(Data1$DATE) - wday(Data1$DATE)
Data2$week <- as.numeric(Data2$DATE) - wday(Data2$DATE)
merge(Data1, Data2, by="week", all=TRUE)

   week     DATE.x VALUE     DATE.y
1 11335       <NA>    NA 2001-01-20
2 11342 2001-01-24    17 2001-01-23
3 11363 2001-02-17    21 2001-02-11
4 11363 2001-02-17    21 2001-02-15
5 11398 2001-03-20    18 2001-03-18
```

Comment: Interesting. I will give this a try later today. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. While this didn't quite solve my problem I feel like I'm on the right track now - treating the dates as numeric was an important first step, and now I'm working on getting the appropriate conditional statements so that values will be assigned appropriately. I appreciate your time in answering my question.